# How to update the Flutter app state after navigating back from Android Java activity?

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

From the Flutter side, using the PlatformChannel, I am navigating to an Android Java activity, and doing some processes.

The activity successfully opens and I'm able to do the functionality and have the final result of it.

How may I navigate back to the Flutter side to a specific page and pass a value?

> P.S.: without going back to the same page and then redirecting to the
> next page.

**On the Flutter side:**
I have these variables

```dart
/// Filters Method Channel
final filtersChannel = const MethodChannel('flutter.native/filters');

/// Filters Method Channel
final filtersResultChannel = const MethodChannel("flutter.native/result_filters");
```

I have a `floatingActionButton` with this function which invokes a `MethodChannel`

```dart
Future<void> startNewActivity() async {
  try {
    await filtersChannel.invokeMethod('open_filters');
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    debugPrint("Failed to Invoke: '${e.message}'.");
  }
}
```

**On the `MainActivity.java`**
On the `protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)` function, I'm starting an activity which has the AR video recording like this:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FiltersActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**On the `FiltersActivity.java`**
On the `public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine)` function

I’m defining and invoking my two channels:

1. The `flutter.native/result_filters` channel which builds the UI and
   the functionality.
2. The `flutter.native/filters` channel which returns the final result.

Here:

```java
@Override
public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);

    String resultFiltersChannelIdentifier = "flutter.native/result_filters";
    filtersResultChannel = new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), resultFiltersChannelIdentifier);

    String filtersChannelIdentifier = "flutter.native/filters";
    MethodChannel filtersChannel = new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), filtersChannelIdentifier);
    filtersChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this::filtersMethodCallHandler);
}
```

Then, the `flutter.native/filters` displays the UI using the filtersMethodCallHandler function. Here:

```java
private void filtersMethodCallHandler(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
    if (methodCall.method.equals("open_filters")) {
        openUI();
    } else {
        result.notImplemented();
    }
}
```

In the openUI function, I'm assigning the record button a function, here:

```java
recordButton.setOnClickListener(this::toggleRecording);
```

And here's the toggleRecording function:

```java
public void toggleRecording(View unusedView) {
    boolean recording = videoRecorder.onToggleRecord();
    if (recording) {
        recordButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_stop);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Started Recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        recordButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.round_videocam);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        videoPath = videoRecorder.getVideoPath().getAbsolutePath();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Video saved: " + videoPath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "Video saved: " + videoPath);
        // Send  notification of updated content.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "Sceneform Video");
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, videoPath);
        getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        filtersResultChannel.invokeMethod("filters_result", videoPath);
        finish();
    }
}
```

As shown above, I'm invoking the `filters_result` method for the `filtersResultChannel` channel and I'm adding the `videoPath` to it.
And then, I'm calling the `finish();` method to close the `FiltersActivity` and return back to the `MainAvtivity` which successfully returns me to the Flutter page!

**BACK to the Flutter side,**
I'm listening to the `filtersResultChannel` like this:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  filtersResultChannel.setMethodCallHandler(_filtersResultHandler);
}

Future _filtersResultHandler(MethodCall methodCall) async {
  if (methodCall.method == "filters_result") {
    final videoPath = methodCall.arguments;
    if (videoPath != null && videoPath.length >= 0) {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        debugPrint("YES YES YES => $videoPath");
        setState(() {
          reportStatus = videoPath;
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => VideoShow(clipPath: videoPath),
            ),
          );
        });
      });
    }
    return null;
  } else {
      return null;
  }
}
```

As shown above, I have a `debugPrint` statement, this statement prints the returned `videoPath` from the `filtersResultChannel`

**<--------->**
**THE PROBLEM**
**<--------->**

Even though I'm successfully getting the `videoPath` value and successfully returning back to the Flutter page, I'm NOT able to use it!!

The `setState();` doesn't update the UI NOR navigate to the next screen, the VideoShow screen!

**HOW MAY I FIX SUCH AN ISSUE?**

Comment: Actually, your question needs to reproduce the code. And if you get any error in the steps, please send the screenshot.

Comment: You don't need a future also Don't use setstate before navigation.